# Periodic Orbit without Complex Eigenvalues

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, differential-equations, bifurcation

I am studying the following ODE system, representing a simple excitable circuit:
$$
\dot{V}_m = I_{app} - (V_m - \alpha_f PL(V_m) + \alpha_s PL(V_s))
$$
$$
\tau_s \dot{V}_s = V_m - V_s 
$$
where
$$
PL(V) = \begin{cases}
-1 & V \leq -1 \\
V & -1 < V < 1 \\
1 & V \geq 1
\end{cases}
$$
At equilibrium, we have $V_m = V_s$, and
$$
I_{app} = \begin{cases}
V_m + \alpha_f - \alpha_s & V_m \leq -1 \\
(1 - \alpha_f + \alpha_s)V_m & -1 < V_m < 1 \\
V_m - \alpha_f + \alpha_s & V_m \geq 1
\end{cases}
$$
with the following possible Jacobians:
$$
J_{V_m \leq -1} = J_{V_m \geq 1} = \begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 0 \\
1/\tau_s & -1/\tau_s
\end{bmatrix}
$$
which has the eigenvalues -1 and $-1/\tau_s$, and
$$
J_{V_m \notin [-1, 1]} = \begin{bmatrix}
-1 + \alpha_f - \alpha_s & 0 \\
1/\tau_s & -1/\tau_s 
\end{bmatrix}
$$
which has the eigenvalues $\lambda_1 = -1/\tau_s$ and $\lambda_2 = \alpha_f - \alpha_s -1$. $\alpha_f$ and $\alpha_s$ must be real, so the system cannot have complex eigenvalues. However, when I plot the phase portrait and do a numerical simulation of the system for $\alpha_f = \alpha_s = 2$, I get a periodic orbit. Is there a way to understand why this is happening?

For context, I was previously using $\tanh$ rather than the $PL$ function, and in that case I was getting a Hopf bifurcation, which gives a nice explanation for the oscillations, but now that I cannot get complex eigenvalues I don't really understand.

Comment: Is $I_\mathrm{app}$ a constant?

Comment: Turns out I had messed up the formula for the Jacobian for $V_m \in (-1, 1)$. The top left entry should be $-1 + \alpha_f$ and the top right one should be $-\alpha_s$, not zero. Now I can get complex eigenvalues. @ChristopheLeuridan yes, Iapp is constant.